# Using only ffmpeg, is it possible to consume a source GIF image and output a video that is a set length > one loop through the input GIF?

Tags: loops, video, ffmpeg, gif, pandastream

Let's say I have an 8 frame animated GIF that is 2 seconds long.  I would like to build a video file (codec not important at this point) that is 30 seconds long that consists of the source GIF repeating over and over.

Is it possible to do this *using only `ffmpeg`?*  Answers that use `convert` or some other pre-processing utility do not count [The reason being that I would like to use this on PandaStream, which does not have that utility].  Let's also assume that shell scripts are out of the question as well, though it can be multiple ffmpeg commands.

---

Things I have tried that did not work (though maybe I did them wrong, I'm not terribly familiar with ffmpeg):

1. Using the `-loop_input`, `-loop_output` options present in the [ffmpeg docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html).  Using both ffmpeg 1.2 and 2.0, I get a `Unrecognized option 'loop_[input|output]'` error message.  I might be using this wrong though since the error is about not recognizing the option, though the docs say it is deprecated.
2. `-loop` option.  Does not seem to do anything with GIF -> Video.  I think this flag and the above flag are related to generating animated GIFs as the output.
3. Concat.  Doing something like:

   ffmpeg -i "concat:image.gif|image.gif|image1.gif|image2.gif|image3.gif|image4.gif" image-long.gif

   Results in a 16 frame gif (so two gifs are concatenated) which is progress, though the output gif is of much lower quality.

---

I'm a bit at my wits end here (I have tried many other permutations of the above concepts), I'm at the point now of 'poking it with a stick', hopefully someone out there has done this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes.

Looking at [How to concatenate (join, merge) media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join%2C%20merge%29%20media%20files#protocol), we can take the gif and transcode to mpeg streams (you could copy the first one twice):

```
ffmpeg -i image.gif -f mpegts image1.ts
ffmpeg -i image.gif -f mpegts image2.ts
ffmpeg -i image.gif -f mpegts image3.ts
```

then concatenate them, outputting as a gif

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:image1.ts|image2.ts|image3.ts" -pix_fmt rgb24 output.gif
```

Starting with an mp4 or similar seems to give better results; replace the first step with

```
ffmpeg -i image.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts image1.ts
```

and repeat for the other copies.

I create multiple copies of the same because if I try to `concat:` the same file multiple times (`concat:image1.ts|image1.ts|image1.ts`) it doesn't work.

Enjoy

Comment: What a hoot. -1 for the accepted answer and no comment. This is why I don't post to Stack Overflow any more.

Comment: but the GIF quality is super pixelated

Comment: @AjayShrestha try adding `-q:v 1` before `-f mpegts` to improve the output quality